# BASH - Join on non-first column

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I am trying to join 2 files together - both files are in CSV format - both files have the same  columns. Here is an example of each file :

File 1:

```
CustName,AccountReference,InvoiceDate,InvoiceRefID,TelNo,Rental,GPRS,Mnet,MnetPlus,SMS,CSD,IntRoaming,NetAmount
acme,107309   ,2011-09-24 12:47:11.000,AP/157371,07741992165     ,2.3900,.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,2.3900
acme,107309   ,2011-09-24 12:58:32.000,AP/162874,07740992165     ,2.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,2.0000
anot,107308   ,2011-09-24 12:58:32.000,AP/162874,07824912428     ,2.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,2.0000
anot,107308   ,2011-09-24 12:47:11.000,AP/157371,07834919928     ,1.5500,.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,.0000,1.5500
```

File 2:

```
CustName,AccountReference,InvoiceDate,InvoiceRefID,TelNo,Rental,GPRS,Mnet,MnetPlus,SMS,CSD,IntRoaming,NetAmount
acme,100046,2011-10-05 08:29:19,AB/020152,07824352342,12.77,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,12.77
anbe,100046,2011-10-05 08:29:19,AB/020152,07741992165,2.50,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2.50
acve,100046,2011-10-05 08:29:19,AB/020152,07740992165,10.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,10.00
asce,100046,2011-10-05 08:29:19,AB/020152,07771335702,2.50,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2.50
```

I would like to join the 2 files together - but just taking some of the columns the other columns can be ignored (some are the same, some are different) -

`AccountRef,telno, rental_file1,rental_file2,gprs_file1,gprs_file2` etc etc ....

The join should be done on the `telno` column (it seems I have white space in file 1 - hope that can be ignored ?

i have found lots of examples using `JOIN` but all of them use the first column for the key on the join .... any pointers would be great - thanks

Comment: AccountRef should be from file1 or from file2? Are the telnums unique per file?

Comment: @DimitreRadoulov AccountRef should be taken from file1 (sorry wasnt clear above) and yes the telno's are unique per file.... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F' *, *' 'NR > 1 && NR == FNR {
  _[$5] = $0; next
  }  
NR == 1 {
  print "AccountReference", "TelNo", "Rental_" ARGV[2], \
  "Rental_" ARGV[3], "GPRS_" ARGV[2], "GPRS_" ARGV[3]
  next
  }
$5 in _ {
  split(_[$5], t)
  print $2, $5, $6, t[6], $7, t[7]
  }' OFS=, file2 file1
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is:

```
join -t , -1 3 -2 4 -1 6 -2 2 file1 file2
```

This will join the files `file1` and `file2` on column 3 from `file` with column 4 from `file2`, then on columns 6 and 2.  The data files must be sorted on those same columns, of course.  The `-t ,` sets the separator for CSV - but `join` will not handle embedded commas inside quoted strings.

If your data is simple (no quoted strings) then you can also use `awk`.  If your data has quoted strings which may contain commas, etc, then you need a CSV-aware tool.  I'd probably use Perl with the [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) module (and the [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) module for performance).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `cat` and `cut` :-)

For instance

```
cat file1 file2 | cut -d, -f2,5
```

yields

```
107309   ,07741992165     
107309   ,07740992165     
107308   ,07824912428     
107308   ,07834919928
100046,07824352342
100046,07741992165
100046,07740992165
100046,07771335702
```

Comment: how about ordering ? can i use sort with cat and cut ?

Comment: sure. that's the whole thing with these commands... they can be combined in just about all ways you can think of :-)

Comment: ok - so say i can order both files by telno - how do I go about joining them on a column - when I say join i mean dont display duplicates - show one occurance of telno with columns from both files ....

Answer (score 0):

All the GNU utilities documented here:

http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/index.html#Top

For your problem, see cat, cut, sort, uniq and join.